# Float on div causing fields to become not editable

Tags: css

I have a problem with float making input fields not editable. When I remove float:left from dvasl class in chrome I can edit fields but then left cloumn is moved to the bottom. I can't find why float is causing this. 
http://www.ipmedia.ee/postkaart/

Comment: Can you post some code? Without it its going to be pretty tough to answer :)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `div` with `class=t2` that is overlapping all your content. What you need to do:

- One Take off the div from the `div class="buttons"` and put it after.
- Two add this porperties for your class `.t2` :

  ```
    .t2 {
        clear:both;
        text-align:right;
    }
  ```

*Tested in your page*

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by float, but by `div.t2` which covers your inputs - it is drawed over your inputs. Try to do something with that. Probably easiest way is to move submit button to another div.

Answer (score 0):

In screen.css you have written a css rule called .buttons
remove the postioning and its works fine

```
.buttons {
height: 24px;
/*position: relative;*/
}
```